# Thread management in a cloned process with CLONE_VM flag set

Tags: linux, multithreading, clone

I need help with thread management inside cloned process.
The point is that I need to create and destroy *threads* inside a cloned process **asynchronously** (`PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` is set). Everything is fine if CLONE_VM is not set, but I need it because main and child process **must** share the same address space. 
Below is an example that demonstrate the question. Being compiled with `CLONE_VM` flag the program hangs at `pthread_join` while without `CLONE_VM` everything is fine.
Are there any ways to deal with this problem?

P.S. Tried at Debian GNU/Linux versions 7,8 and unstable (kernels 3.2, 3.16, 4.0).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Compile with # gcc -o pthread_test -lpthread pthread_test.c */

#define CLONE 1

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_test(void *unused)
{
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pause();
    return NULL;
}

int test(void *unused)
{
    void *status;
    int r;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if ((r = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_test, NULL)) != 0) {
        printf("pthread_create returned %d\n", r);
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("cancelling thread\n");
    r = pthread_cancel(thread);
    printf("pthread cancel returned : %s(%d)\n", strerror(r), r);
    printf("joining thread\n");
    r = pthread_join(thread, &status);
    printf("pthread_join returned : %s\n", strerror(r));
    if (status == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        printf("child was canceled\n");
    else
        printf("child exit status is %u\n", (unsigned)status);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
#if CLONE
    void *stack = (void *)malloc(16384);
    if (clone(test, stack + 16383, CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("clone failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    waitpid(0, NULL, __WCLONE);
    return 0;
#else
    void *stack = (void *)malloc(16384);
    if (clone(test, stack + 16383, /*CLONE_VM |*/ CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("clone failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    waitpid(0, NULL, __WCLONE);
    return 0;
#endif
}
```